# PHP Lightbox images loaded from server

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, lightbox

Okay i`m loading images from a MySql Database server.. but when i click on it, it opens in a new page not in the lightbox popup.

```
                // Make the connect to MySQL or die
                // and display an error.
                $db = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
                if (!$db) {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

                // Select your database
                mysql_select_db ($database); 

                $categorie = $_GET['categorie'];
                echo "<h3>" . $categorie . "</h3><br><br>";


                $query = "SELECT * FROM afbeelding WHERE categorie = '" . $categorie . "'";
                $resultaat = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error());

                echo "<table>";

                while ($rij = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat)){
                     echo "<a href=" . $rij["afbeelding"] . " rel=\"lightbox[roadtrip]\"><img src=" . $rij["afbeelding"] . " width=\"150px\" height=\"150px\" class='foto' /></a>";
                    }

                    echo "</table>";
                ?>
```

Please some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're loading you images after the page is loaded, you might want to call the function that initiates the lightbox *after* the images arrive.

Comment: Could you please show me how?.. i`m a starting php user.. i`m only making this site as a subject for my college.

Comment: Are you using AJAX to get the images? If not, then my answer doesn't really apply... You should check out the next answer about the css class. This isn't a PHP issue. It's html + javascript.

Comment: check the code you get after the page is loaded and see if it's identical to the one you get when you insert the images to html manually. If it works one way and doesn't work the other - there must be a difference.

Comment: shall i send you the entire code? cause i dont really get the code

Comment: It would be better if you could paste you code here http://jsfiddle.net/ and give me the link. No PHP though, only html+javascript+css. But if you succeed in doing this I can tell you what your PHP should look like.

Comment: Oooh... Sorry, that's not working... Too much of everything and php is still there, etc. Forget about it. Try removing PHP and using plain HTML for images. If the images work that way - send me the HTML code you used.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hc4nT/

There the lightbox works perfectly... tryed the same with the php.. should work.. just doesnt

Comment: what does your PHP output? Check the source of the page.

Comment: You should know i`m a noob on programming hahaha.. But you could see in the code up what the php source is..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set correct CSS class for your `<A>`, otherwise lightbox JS will not take care of it.

Comment: Never needed to do that even on other images and it still worked.